# Output for svn diff not generating expected contents

Tags: svn, diff

When I run the following command from my working directory:

```
svn diff > c:\temp\diff-results.diff
```

I expect the diff-results.diff file to store the modifications I made to files in my working directory, instead I see output that looks like this:

```
Index: MyClass.cs
==================================================
c:\repository>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Beyond Compare 2\BC2.exe" "MyProject\.svn\text-base\MyClass.cs.svn-base" /title1="MyClass.cs  (revision 481282)" "MyClass.cs" /title2="MyClass.cs (working copy)"
```

So my question is how do I get this to store the actual changes I made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happened because I customized subversion to run a specific diff program (Beyond Compare).  I ran the following command and saw the expected results:

```
svn diff --diff-cmd diff > c:\temp\diff-results.diff
```